# Cursor и выборка значений

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

Продолжаю рубрику безответных вопросов на Stack overflow.

**Имеем: DB.java**

```
Cursor Positions (String str){
  NAME = str;
  cursor = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE", null);
  result = cursor.getColumnCount();
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  for (int k = 1; k < result; k++) {
      cur = DB.rawQuery("SELECT _id," + NAME + " FROM TABLE WHERE A" + k + " = 1", null);
  }  
  return cur;
  }
```

**Дано:**
*NAME* задаём сами, в данном случае я поставил *BIT* для удобства, *n* - аналогично.

**MainActivity.java**

```
                            cur4 = DB.Positions("BIT");
                            List<String>lt2 = new ArrayList<String>();
                            String add2 = null;
                            cur4.moveToFirst();
                            for (int i = 0; i < cur4.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                                add2 = cur4.getString(i);
                                lt2.add(add2);
                            }
                            ad2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.my_textview, lt2);
                            lv1.setAdapter(ad2);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Строку *BIT* необходимо записать в `cursor` с `Ak = 1`.
Предположим в в таблице содержится строка `0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0`, после неизвестных мне манипуляций, мы получим cursor `1 1 1`, что будет соответствовать `А2`, `А4`, `А5`.
Вариант реализации через `List` я уже практиковал, совсем недавно мне сказали, что данный метод, мягко говоря, ложный (через `List` несерьёзно работать с `ListView`, работай через `cursor`).
Поэтому сам вопрос, как это реализовать?

Comment: Вы путаетесь в терминологии, от этого, возможно, ваши вопросы и безответны. Приведите структуру таблицы, тестовые данные, и результат выборки, которые вы хотите получить. Код в вашем вопросе ничего полезного не делает и понять проблему не помогает.

Comment: Если вы подскажите, какие ещё данные нужно добавить, я добавлю. Значит у меня проблемы с объяснением.

Comment: `В строке BIT необходимо записать` - это всё ещё sqlite?

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: name можно перенести в where, а k добавить к полям(как константу), тогда в результате будут искомые `null,2,null,4,5`

Comment: вообще, табличку нормализовать бы...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. База данных не работает так, как вы ожидаете. Выбраны могут быть только строки, соответствующие условию, и для всех отобранных строк вы можете запросить какие-то столбцы, которые есть в таблицах, участвующих в выборке, заранее известные (в худшем случае все).
2. Если вам нужно отбирать столбцы по какому-то критерию, значит у вас неверная структура данных.
3. Судя по всему вы спутали базу данных (точнее таблицу) с экселем.
4. Задача, которую вы решаете, вызвала трудности уже на ранней стадии, возможно стоило сначала задать вопрос о самой задаче, методах и путях ее решения, а потом решать местечковые проблемы.

**Например**, если вы хотите хранить матрицы, то для этого правильней использовать такую структуру:

```
create table matrix (row, col, value);
```

и содержать она будет понятное дело значения по соответствующим координатам:

```
...
insert into matrix values (2,1,0);
insert into matrix values (2,2,1);
insert into matrix values (2,3,0);
insert into matrix values (2,4,1);
insert into matrix values (2,5,1);
insert into matrix values (2,6,0);
...
```

Если вы хотите именовать строки и столбцы, это можно сделать в отдельных таблицах:

```
create table rows (id, name);
create table cols (id, name);
```

и наполнить их:

```
...
insert into rows values (2,'BIT');
...
insert into cols values (1,'A1');
insert into cols values (2,'A2');
insert into cols values (3,'A3');
insert into cols values (4,'A4');
insert into cols values (5,'A5');
insert into cols values (6,'A6');
...
```

Запрос для вашего курсора:

```
select cols.name
from matrix m
  join cols on m.col = cols.id
  join rows on m.row = rows.id
where
  m.value = 1 and rows.name='BIT';
```

В результате будет:

```
====
name
====
A2
A4
A5
```

ЗЫ Если имена строк и колонок можно вычислить, то можно их не хранить, а вычислять в запросе или в постобработке: в коде.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, как только получу положительный результат, сразу отпишусь и сделаю отметку! Столбцы могут удаляться в случайной последовательности.

Comment: Все работает, спасибо! Единственное для курсора перед cols.name добавил cols.id.